# AWS lambda with both python and java language support

Tags: java, python, automation, aws-lambda

Our institution is trying to make an automatic grading platform set up for an introductory class in java, and we were hoping to use an AWS lambda function for the grading. The problem is, like any sane person, our dev team far prefers python over java, so the grader itself is written in python, but the student programs are written in java.

Since the grader has to call the student functions, it would be best if we could have a lambda runtime that has binaries for both python and java. Does anyone else know how we could go about doing that?

As a side note, it would be possible to use a separate function to run the java files and return the output to the python function, but since amazon charges per function execution, this would be less than ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do this with a regular python or java runtime and use a lot of trickery to get the other interpreter into your environment, but that's far from ideal.

Your case calls for a custom runtime - more information about which you can find in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html). Essentially they let you take any language and/or binaries and put them in a Lambda Function so you should be able to build yourself a runtime with python and java in it.

Depending on the time the function takes to run it might be more cost effective and easier to have a Fargate container listening to an SQS queue and process the requests asynchronously. Docker containers are typically easier to build (or at least better understood) and for longer-running tasks this will most likely be more cost effective.

Comment: For a most part the tasks will run in under two seconds, with a worst-case runtime being about 15 seconds. The automatic grading will be interfaced with github classrooms, so a synchronous response would be preferred. Is it possible to have synchronous responses with Fargate?

Comment: In that case you'd either need to expose the Fargate Container to the Internet to serve as an API-Endpoint or place the fargate container inside of an ECS Service behind an Application Load Balancer (you could even integrate the ALB with the API Gateway if that fits your use case). This will be more expensive than the asynchronous version. With a runtime of up to 15 seconds you might run into timeout problems with synchronous responses, but that's a different question ;-)